# Using Visual Studio Code with Arduino

Tags: ide

I'm trying to figure out how you can work with multiple sketches using Visual Studio Code and the Arduino.

Let's say I have three projects that I want to actively develop.

```
Motors.ino
Motors_with_controls.ino
Motors_with_lights.ino
```

Each one is a different project, but I want to quickly be able to upload one, then upload another.

My folder for Visual Studio Code is set up as such:

```
ArduinoProjects
   .vscode
       arduino.json
       c_cpp_properties.json
   Motors
       Motors.ino
   Motors_with_controls
       Motors_with_controls.ino
   Motors_with_lights
       Motors_with_lights.ino
```

But it seems like the only way to upload a particular ino is to go into the arduino.json file and hand edit the "sketch" parameter.

```
"sketch": "Motors\\Motors.ino"
```

Is there a quicker way? Ideally I'd like it to upload the ino I am currently editing without having to go and edit the arduino.json file.